# WooCommerce - разные цены для одного товара в зависимости от выбора в select

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Есть магазин, у которого три адреса (физических). По трём адресам цены на товары разные, нужно сделать так, чтобы при выборе пользователем на сайте того или иного магазина цены подстраивались. Кастомные поля для цен добавил, проблема с выводом значения из селекта и дальнейшей передачей его. Понял, что нужно использовать сессии, но как именно загнать значение из селекта в сессию?

Comment: не знаком с особенностями woocommerce, но как то так я думаю будет работать <?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test']='Hello world!';

echo $_SESSION['test'];

Comment: @Дмитрий в WP сессия всегда запущена.

Answer (score 0):

- вам нужно повесить фильтр на хук перед добавлением в корзину.
  с условием брать какое место выбрано пользователем и сравнивать с тем, что какие цены должны быть для него и переписывать в корзине значения.

там кода много, двумя строчками не обойдешься

Answer (score 0):

Если три физических магазина находятся в разных городах, то вам поможет плагин [WT Geotargeting Pro](https://web-technology.biz/cms-wordpress/plugin-wt-geotargeting/).

Начиная с версии 1.7.6 появилась возможность добавлять разные цены для товаров WooCommerce с привязкой к городам.

Теоретически, даже если магазины находятся в одном городе, их адреса можно добавить как отдельные регионы и так-же добавлять разные цены.

**Для реализации описанного вам необходимо:**

1. Установить и активировать плагин WT Geotargeting Pro.
2. Добавить в панели администратора регионы (города или адреса магазинов).
3. Добавить на страницы сайта [выбор региона](https://web-technology.biz/cms-wordpress/plugin-wt-geotargeting-for-cms-wordpress/vybor-goroda/).
4. Отключить геолокацию (если не нужна).
5. Активировать в настройках поддержку плагина WooCommerce.
6. Добавить новые цены на странице редактирования товара.

[image: Добавление региональной цены товара WooCommerce]